# Run time error 5 on vb6, error log shows "Class TabDlg.SSTab of control SSTab1 was not a loaded control class"

Tags: vb6

I have a vb6 exe file that has been stable and working for several years now.  When I run the installation file on another computer, I get run time error 5.  There are several forms that have the SSTab Dialog on them.  In the logs for these particular forms I get the following msg. "Class TabDlg.SSTab of control SSTab1 was not a loaded control class"  In checking the installed components, the Microsoft Tabbed Dialog is selected.  I am totally lost, any help please?!?!?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem this week.
In my case, the OCX file was in folder SisWOW64. I just copied it to folder System32 and returned work like a charm!
***VB6 still alive***

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time i had no vb6 activity. But some solutions include:
- Check the folder of the ocx to see the OCX file exists. (You can see the path and name of the ocx when you click on the control name in Components dialog).
- Uncheck the control and check it again.
- Also check the Refrences dialog to see if its control is loaded there too?